# Why can't the compiler detect that functions are constant without annotating them with const?

Tags: rust, ctfe

In Rust, `const` functions are quite limited in what code can be put inside them, e.g. `for` loops aren't allowed, nor are any non-`const` function calls. I understand that there are issues with heap allocations in `const` functions, but why is it that for example the below code isn't valid:

```rust
fn add(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
    a + b
}
const A: u8 = add(1, 2);
```

This would be valid if `add` was declared as a `const` function.

- Why can't the Rust compiler detect that this is valid?
- Why are `const` functions necessary at all?
- Why aren't even `for` loops allowed inside them (even though while `loop`s are)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why are const functions necessary at all?

Constant functions are declared `const` to tell the compiler that this function is allowed to be called from a `const` context. Const-eval is done in a tool called [`miri`](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri/). Miri is not capable of evaluating all expressions, and so `const` functions are pretty limited. There is a [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57563) of extensions that have been accepted and there is active work going on to make them const-compatible.

> Why can't the Rust compiler detect that this is valid?

While technically possible, the Rust team decided against it. The primary reason being semantic versioning issues. Changing the body of a function, without changing the signature, could make that function no longer const-compatible and break uses in a const-context. `const fn` is a contract, and breaking that contract is an explicit breaking change.

> Why aren't even for loops allowed inside them (even though while loops are)?

As to why `for` loops aren't allowed, they technically are. The only problem is that the `Iterator::next` method is not `const`, meaning that not some iterators may perform operations that are not const-evaluatable. Until a language construct that allows trait methods to be marked as `const`, or the ability to put `const` *bounds*, you will have to stick to regular `loop`s.

```rust
const fn looop(n: usize) {
    let mut i = 0;
    loop {
        if i == n {
            return;
        }
        // ...
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We annotate `const` functions for the same reason we annotate `pub` functions: to make our intentions clear to the user. If you're writing a `const` function, you probably know it and are doing so intentionally (since, as you've stated, `const` functions are very limited in what they can do). By annotating it with a keyword, you

1. Communicate very clearly to all callers that this is intended as a `const` function,
2. Allow the compiler to verify that rather than silently letting it pass if you accidentally do something non-`const` in it, and
3. Guarantee that future changes to this function's implementation won't cause problems downstream if someone wrongly assumed a function was or wasn't `const`.

As for the for loops, they're just not the intention. If you want to do compile-time code generation, we have a whole subsystem for that: it's called macros and it's amazing. `const fn` is for short functions that can be used in runtime context but that allow the added optimization of running at compile-time. As such, something like a loop (which may or may not terminate) adds a lot of complexity to that, and it can cause the compiler to fail to terminate. There are lots of infinite iterators, and determining whether the iteratee is infinite or not is equivalent to the halting problem. So it's easier to keep it simple and disallow this.

Comment: From [the RFC adding `while` and `loop` support](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2344-const-looping.md) it certainly looks like `for` is intended as well, just left for the future.

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't the Rust compiler detect that this is valid?

It can. The reason it *won't* is that removing `const` is a backwards-incompatible change, and so must be opt-in: as the developer, by publishing a `const` function you're making a very specific promise to user. Having the const-ness of a function automatically change without warnings based on its implementation details would be terrible.

It's very similar to the reason why `Copy` isn't automatically implemented as soon as it could be: removing `Copy` breaks code, so `Copy` needs to be a guarantee which is opted into, while it's technically trivial change, it's absolutely not an *innocuous* change.

> Why are const functions necessary at all?

Because the alternative (something like Zig's comptime or C++'s templates) doesn't really jive with Rust's safety philosophy, as well as its Elm-inspired desire to provide somewhat useful compiler errors.

> Why aren't even for loops allowed inside them (even though while loops are)?

Have you considered looking? There's literally an RFC which tells you that: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2344-const-looping.html

> `for` loops are technically allowed, too, but can't be used in practice because each iteration calls `iterator.next()`, which is not a `const fn` and thus can't be called within constants. Future RFCs (like https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2237) might lift that restriction.

Comment: Couldn't editions solve the backward compatibility issues?

Comment: Because that's not their purpose, and const, like copy, is a problem which applies to *the entire ecosystem*, editions only apply to the core distribution.