# Is it possible to const assert trait const value equality?

Tags: rust, assertion

I have some example code, in where I tried to use `static_assertions` crate. But I am not sure it is even possible.

```rust
use static_assertions::{const_assert_eq, const_assert_ne};

pub trait Foo {
    const ID: &'static str;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Foo for A {
    const ID: &'static str = "A";
}

impl Foo for B {
    const ID: &'static str = "B";
}


const fn assert_ids() {
    const_assert_ne!(A::ID, B::ID);
}

fn main() {
    assert_ids();
    println!("Compiles successfully!");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cedbd3a84309fa003b6da1f7f37fcc98)

Fails compiling with:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  --> src\main.rs:35:5
   |
35 |     const_assert_ne!(A::ID, B::ID);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `const_assert_ne` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I have been reading on some threads like:

- [Rust limits on const functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940956/rust-limits-of-const-functions),
- [Cons expressions inside trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049189/const-expressions-inside-trait)

but couldn't related it.

EDIT:

When changing the type to `usize` in the trait:

```rust
pub trait Foo {
    const ID: usize;
}
```

The above example works. So I guess it may be related to the type being `&'static str`.

Comment: Just a note: since Rust 1.57, you don't need the static-assertions crate and can use `assert!()` directly: `const _: () = assert!(...);`. You also get better diagnostics (unfortunately, you cannot use `assert_eq!()` and `assert_ne!()` yet, [since they rely on a non-`const` `fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/panicking.rs.html#135-146)).

Comment: You can also create a `static_assert!()` macro quite easily, for conveience: `macro_rules! static_assert { ($($t:tt)*) => { const _: () = $($t)*; }; }`, then `static_assert!(A::ID == B::ID);`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, nice notes, definetly gonna use plain `assert!`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`str::eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq) is not const. For now you can only compare primitive type such as integers, chars, bools. I don't know if there is a tracking issue for str and slice. [#67792](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792)

So yes it's possible but not with `str`:

```rust
pub trait Foo {
    const ID: i32;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Foo for A {
    const ID: i32 = 42;
}

impl Foo for B {
    const ID: i32 = 3;
}

const fn assert_ids() {
    if A::ID == B::ID {
        panic!("nooooo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_ids();
    println!("Compiles successfully!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Stargateur! It makes sensse. I dont know the magic behind `const_str` though. Something to take a look.

Comment: @Netwave a good old loop https://github.com/Nugine/const-str/blob/master/const-str/src/bytes.rs#L14

Comment: awesome! Actually that may solve my next issue, because I want to check a matrix of those ids while keeping const!

Answer (score 3):

A combination of [`const_str`](https://docs.rs/const-str/0.3.1/const_str/#) and [`static_assertions`](https://docs.rs/static_assertions/latest/static_assertions/index.html) crates worked for the purpose:

```rust
use static_assertions::{const_assert};
use const_str;

pub trait Foo {
    const ID: &'static str;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Foo for A {
    const ID: &'static str = "A";
}

impl Foo for B {
    const ID: &'static str = "B";
}


const fn assert_ids() {
    const_assert!(!const_str::equal!(A::ID, B::ID));
}

fn main() {
    assert_ids();
    println!("Compiles successfully!");
}
```

As per @ChayimFriedman suggestion, since rust `1.57` it is possible to use plain `assert!`:

```rust
const _: () = assert!(const_str::equal!(A::ID, B::ID));
```